# Can't Find bundle org.osgi.annotations in Eclipse RCP App

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp, osgi-bundle

I'm trying to use a framework extension in my RCP app using the instructions [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Adaptor_Hooks#The_Base_Adaptor).

To run the framework extension in my workspace, I;m instructed to import the org.eclipse.osgi plug-in as a source bundle. When I do that, I get lots of compile errors because the bundle org.osgi.annotations is not available. Of course org.eclipse.osgi doesn't need the annotations at runtime, but since I have to load this bundle in my workspace at development time, I'm left with lots of unresolved compile errors.

I searched around quite a bit, and can't find the org.osgi.annotations bundle. Anyone know where I can get it?

Comment: it's here : http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.osgi%7Cosgi.annotation%7C6.0.1%7Cjar

Comment: Thanks. osgi.annotation-6.0.1.jar has exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official download is on the [OSGi Alliance website](https://www.osgi.org/developer/downloads/release-6/release-6-download/). On this page you are looking for "OSGi Core Release 6 Annotation Code".

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, although the page loads, the link for the annotation code link is broken, returns a 404. The other links work. I was able to get the code from the maven link provided by Jérémie in a comment to my question. I'd like to report the broken link, but I didn't see a way to do that on the site, apart from joining an e-mail group and/or registering, which I didn't want to do.

Comment: The link is fixed now.